# stop postback on asp .net chart control click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-charts

I have a chart with aspx code as below.

```
<asp:Chart ID="FirstTimeBuildPercentage" runat="server" ToolTip="First time Build Statistics" ImageType="Jpeg" Width="980px" Height="400px" BackColor="#D3DFF0" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" Palette="EarthTones" class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
```

On page load I bind the chart to data from a server-side data source.
However, once the chart is rendered, clicking on it anywhere causes the page to postback. 
I have removed the 'OnClick', it still didn't help in avoiding postback.
While I inspected the client-side HTML, I see inside the map element there are multiple "__doPostBack" with some params.
I do not want any postback event to be fired on click of the chart.

Note: I tried the following already and nothing helped.

```
1) AutoPostBack="false"
2) EnableViewState="true"
3) OnClientClick="return false;"
4) onclick="<javascript..method>"
```

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this question

Comment: try this :
OnClientClick="javascript:return false;"

Comment: doesn't work :/